# How to add more localizations to my Xcode Project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, localization

I've already localized my Xcode Project once, but i don't know how to add more languages. I can't find the "+" button.
I have my .xib and .strings in English and Portuguese.
Here's what i see:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the localizations to your project:

[image]

Then you can simply select the localizations for each file separately.