# How to add localization to Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, localization

I try to add Localization to my project  but its not working.

this is the steps i do.

After create a new project,

i add "**Localizations**" in Info file (LangDemo-Info.plist) and then add Languages (English & French).

[image]

now i add Localizable.strings file to my project

after this in 'Locatization panel' asking "Localize"

[image]

after click Localize button, its show alert message

[image]

if click Localize button, "English" language will add in the Locatization Panel

[image]

there is no "+" button ?

How can I add next language? I'm using **Xcode 4.6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found solution for this

i just refer those links

[How to add more localizations to my Xcode Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378477/how-to-add-more-localizations-to-my-xcode-project)

http://www.aboveground.com/blog/xcode-4-4-and-localizable-strings-no-way-to-add-language

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the Ray Wenderlich tutorial on Localization. http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial